# RS FEC correct more than t/2 errors sometimes... why is this happening?

Tags: channelcoding, forward-error-correction, coding

According to the [Reed-Solomon Wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction), the RS code can correct up to $\lfloor\frac{t}{2}\rfloor$.

While I was playing around with Reed-Solomon FEC ([github repo](https://github.com/rotorgit/reedsolomon)), I noticed that sometimes the RS(544, 514, t=30, m=10) can correct more than 15 symbol errors. Based on the wiki page above, this RS coding scheme should be able to correct only up to 15 symbol errors. However, I observed that this RS code could sometimes correct 16~18 symbol errors (but not always!).

Now I am curious why this is happening in RS code and what would be the most intuitive way to understand this phenomenon. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could share your knowledge about this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware: what you're seeing could be the result of a bug in your code.

Having said that: in general, algebraic codes such as BCH and RS are very hard to decode using algebraic algorithms. Practical decoding algorithms are called "minimum distance decoders": they guarantee they can correct a certain number of errors (15 in your case), but they **do not** guarantee that they cannot correct a greater number. This constraint makes the decoding problem tractable.

Note that almost all codes have the potential to correct more errors than the minimum-distance alone would indicate. Only "perfect codes", of which there's only a handful, have the property of not being able to correct more than $\lfloor t/2 \rfloor$ errors.

In other words, practical decoders for algebraic codes leave a lot of performance on the table, and that is part of the reason these codes have been out of fashion for a while. I highly recommend reading McKay's book on information theory (available online for free) and also this website for an astonishing recently-developed decoder: https://www.granddecoder.mit.edu/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the book recommendations and this nice-looking GRAND decoder. I will check this out. I still do have some questions about the mystery about correcting more than t/2 errors: I understand that the practical decoding algorithm is minimum distance decoder in the codeword space.  However, if I have more than t/2 errors, this means that the received (and corrupted) codewords will be more close to the other codewords than what it was sent originally. This is why I was not sure how can a RS decoder can correct greater than t/2 sometimes...

Comment: The minimum distance is the "worst case", but the weight distribution is not necessarily uniform in all codes. Consider a code with three elements: "000000", "000001", and "111111". The minimum distance is 1, but the error pattern "110000" can be corrected: the word closest to "001111" is "111111", the word closest to "110000" is "000000", and the word closest to "110001" is "000001". Not all error patterns with more errors than `floor(t/2)` can be fixed, but some of them can. This particular example is extreme, but the same thing happens in all non-perfect codes.

Comment: thanks a lot for detailed explanation !